# A required field in form must now be made optional with a new field becoming required while having an optional relationship to the original field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

**Background:**
I'm working on an pre-existing code base that has already been live in production for years. Nuking the DB is not an option.

**TLDR** We have a web form with values that map back to a DB table, a form and value and its associated schema currently are set as required. We want to add another value to the form which will become required, but also making the aforementioned value optional.

**Current State:**
Imagine a web form with a field, "transaction numbers" that maps back to a schema like this

```rb
 create_table "transaction", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "transaction_number", null: false
    t.integer "entry_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "rep_id"
    t.index ["entry_id", "transaction_number"], name: "index_trans_on_entry_id_and_trans_number", unique: true
  end
```

In this current setup, a transaction number is required (and has been since the application has existed).

The challenge is to now add another field to the web form, let's call it `parts_number`.

Adding the field bring on new requirements:

1. A transaction/transaction_number will be *optional* going forward
2. `parts_number` will become *required*
3. A form submission must always include `parts_number` and *might* include a transaction_number, but not necessarily

It can be said that there is a one-to-one/one-to-none relationship between `parts_number` and `transaction_number`.

Given that in the current, original, version we query on transactions, it seems we'd have to change how we do queries since going forward all data will require `parts_number` and *sometimes* have `transaction_number`, but all historical data will continue have `transaction_number` but never `parts_number`. Doing a migration of historical data to suddenly have `parts_number` is also not an option.

What might be a good approach for this?

Is there a way this can be approached safely?

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely cannot migrate `parts_number` to any reasonable value, an option could be to create an STI model where you define the type for your records. Keep in mind the naming should not be `Old<Name>` and `New<Name>` - make them descriptive so they map to something from your domain.

Once you have STI in place:

- populate the type for old records
- define validations on a new model, make sure you create new records with the new type
- make sure any query is aware of this difference (query will always include type one way or another - if you query old data)

This is in my opinion cleanest way. It is all in the code and there is no questionable logic with magical constant containing date when things changed (I've seen it), there is no if statements on validations containing it and the domain maps it correctly as well. If you changed the business logic, model you had does no longer map the reality and it makes sense to name it different as well.

Hope this helps and makes sense! Curious also what other people think.